# Tensorflow 2.4.0 RAM continues grow when CNN training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have built a simple CNN using tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0 for cifar10

```
# Set constent
num_classes = len(label_names)  # The number of classes
input_shape = (32, 32, 3)       # The input shape 32 * 32 pixels, 3 RGB brightness for each pixel

# Construct a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Starting add layers to the model
# First VGG blockes
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())     # BatchNormalization after convolutional layer
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())     # BatchNormalization after convolutional layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))     # MaxPooling2D to keep important features as well as shirnk info size
model.add(Dropout(0.1))             # Drop some portion of nodes to increase generality of model

# Second VGG blockes
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Third VGG blockes
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# Fourth VGG blockes
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Flat and dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Final softmax layer
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# The optimizer gives the learning rate lr and some other parameters.
opt = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

# Model complie
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And while I am training this model:

```
#Train model
epochs = 100
batch_size = 128

# create data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                             width_shift_range=5,
                             height_shift_range=5,
                             rotation_range=20)

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_training, y_training, batch_size=batch_size),
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=(x_validate, y_validate),
                    verbose=1,
                    shuffle=True)
```

The RAM of my computer keeps grow until the training process crashes. Adding python garbage collector for at end of each epoch did not work. Disabling eager detection did not work.

I using
tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0
CUDA 11.0
cuDNN 8.0